# jQuery - Sum up two Values of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i´ve wanted to sum up theese two into one total ... i tried to many things yet ... but nothing worked ... maybe someone could help me? and if i show the 2nd of October go back to the first of october and again to the 2nd my total price of tea cups remain, nevertheless i set the value back to nothing/zero ...

maybe it could be dissolved by just one equotation?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function einblenden(){
        var land   = document.getElementById('tea-date').selectedIndex;
        if(land == 1) {
document.getElementById('tea').style.display = "block";   
document.getElementById('tea-sum').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('tea-input').value = ""; }
            else {
document.getElementById('tea').style.display = "none";  
document.getElementById('tea-sum').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('tea-input').value = "";
}        }
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("#tea-seat").bind("keyup change", function(e){ var val1 = jQuery("#tea-seat").val(); var val2 = 30; jQuery("#tea-sum").text(val1*val2); }); 
jQuery("#tea-input").bind("keyup change", function(e){ var val3 = jQuery("#tea-input").val(); var val4 = 17.50; jQuery("#tea-cup-sum").text(val3*val4); }); 
});
// ]]></script>
```

```html
<p>Date*     
        <select name="tea-date" id="tea-date" onchange="einblenden();">
            <option value="1. Oct 2016">1. Oct 2016</option>
            <option value="2. Oct 2016">2. Oct 2016</option>
        </select>

<p>Seats*<br />
[number* tea-seats min:1 max:50 default:1 id:tea-seat]</p>

        <div id="tea" style="display: none;">
<p>reserve tea<br>( 17.50 $/cup)<br />
[number cup-tea min:0 max:50 default:0 id:tea-input] Cup/s</p>
        </div>

<p><strong>Total Price of seats: <span id="tea-sum"></span> Money</strong></p>
      
<p><strong>Total Price of Tea Cups: <span id="tea-cup-sum"></span> Money</strong></p>

<p><strong>Total Price of everything: <span id="total-tea"></span> Money</strong></p>

<p>[submit "submit text"]</p>
```

Comment: There are no input elements nor elements with those id's with the HTML you provided. Also you commented out the closing `</script>`.

Comment: sorry wasn´t ready yet ... my bad ... I´m new ...

Comment: Your html is still invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure what you're trying to do with all that stuff, but this here is a tiny example:

```
$(document).ready((function() {
  var setValue = function() {
      var seats = parseFloat($("#tea-sum").val());
      var cups = parseFloat($("#tea-cup-sum").val());
      $("#total-tea").val(seats+cups);
  }
    $("#tea-sum").change(setValue);
  $("#tea-cup-sum").change(setValue);
}))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zp88wmfv/

What you're missing: The field could contain letters or invalid formatted numbers. You probably wouldn't want input fields in this way either.